# Border-top aparece pela metade no iOS

Tags: ios, sass, jekyll

No `iOS` o parâmetro `border-top` é mostrado até a metade da tela, no PC ele aparece com 100% de width normalmente.

Como fazer ele aparecer com 100% de width no iOS tambem?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o SCSS:

```
.wrapper-masthead {
border-top: 7px solid $amarelo;
background: $white;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
  @include mobile {
    position: inherit;
  }
}
```

Código completo: https://github.com/sistematico/sistematico.github.io/blob/master/css/style.scss

Comment: De uma olhada no comportamento responsivo da tela. Não acho que seja o problema com a bordar, talvez tenha algum outro elemento que esteja quebrando o layout.

Comment: @LucasRomano aí que tá o problema, me perdi nessa aí...

Comment: Você tá usando alguma _meta tag_ pra ajustar o viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Possíveis problemas:

**1 - Largura do elemento**

```
width: 100%;
```

Essa medida é relativa ao próximo elemento (de maior hierarquia) que tem largura declarada. Se o próximo elemento tiver `50px` de largura o seu filho que esta com 100% de largura também o terá.

```
.pai{
  width:50px;
}

.pai .filho{
    width:100%; /* 50px */
}
```

**2 - Viewport**

Inclua um viewport na sua página (caso não tenha uma) para que você possa controlar com mais facilidade o tamanho dos elementos e trata-los com media-query de forma precisa.

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

**3 - Position**

```
@include mobile {
  position: inherit;
}
```

Esse trecho esta incluindo o position do elemento com maior hierarquia que possui position declarado. Evite colocar dessa forma pois há mais chance de alguma mudança no layout alterar a posição desse elemento de forma inesperada. Talvez o melhor uso nesse caso fosse position static que é o default da propriedade position:

```
@include mobile {
  position: static;
}
```